# "If" and "Whether" - Is interrogative IF always replacable by WHETHER?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses, questions, subordinators

I am asking here specifically about *if* and *whether*  when they introduce embedded questions (or to be more technically accurate, subordinate interrogative clauses):

- I don't know if Bob's here.
- I don't know whether Bob's here.

In the sentence above we can freely replace *if* with *whether*. There are some situations in which the reverse does not apply. We cannot always replace *whether* with *if*. For example in standard English, we cannot normally use *if* after a preposition:

- The question of whether he is actually eligible didn't arise.
- *The question of if he is actually eligible didn't arise.

We cannot usually use interrogative-*if* directly followed by *or not*:

- It's unclear *whether or not* he's a real elephant.
- *It's unclear *if or not* he's a real elephant.

There are several more examples. However, what I want to know is:

- Are there any examples where we can use interrogative-*if* but we can't use *whether*?

---

<sup>Edit note: There is an *if* that we find in conditionals that can't be replaced by *whether*. However, this is conditional, not interrogative, *if*.</sup>

Comment: *It's unclear if he's a real elephant or not.*

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, indeed. But that *if* isn't (directly) followed by *or not*! :)

Comment: Use *whether* only in an embedded clause (or a *whether or not* construction). That is the rule here. You can't say *Whether you walk out that door, don't come back!*

Comment: @jlovegren As far as I'm aware, the same goes for interrogative "if" too. If we use an *if*-clause as an adjunct (i.e. as an adverbial) it will have a conditional reading, not an interrogative one: "If he gets this right, he'll win the competition", for example.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me.  Might be good to tell me why my solution was not useful.  This is why I hate posting on stackexchange.  Why do I even help?  Deleted a good solution and won't be posting in this English area again.

Comment: _Whether_ is the interrogative _Wh_-word for Yes/No questions, which don't normally use a _Wh_-word (_When is he coming?_ but not *_Whether is he coming?_). It only shows up when a Yes/No question is an embedded question complement clause and needs a _Wh_-word to use as a complementizer (_I don't know when/whether he is coming_). Since Yes/No questions always give two alternatives, _if_ can always be substituted for _whether_, but not the other way around. So study how to use _whether_, not _if_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the advice, but I'm asking as a (student) linguist. I'm a native speaker!! I'm trying to show that conditional antecedents are interrogative clauses (which doesn't mean, of course, that they represent  questions). I'm looking at data in order to try and show that conditional and interrogative *if* are the same item. Conditional *if* cannot be substituted by *whether*. One example where interrogative *if* can likewise not be substituted would be helpful. I do in fact have one example, but its grammaticality seems to be slightly questionable although ...

Comment: @JohnLawler ... I have found hundreds of examples in printed books.

Comment: Inability to substitute is the test for "conditional if". So there are two kinds until you find a different test.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, one area where I've found that that fails is in governed exhaustive conditional constructions. In particular with the phrase *no matter*. So in "No matter if he meant to do it or not, he did it, and so is going to be punished" conditional *if* may be replaced by *whether*. The example of somewhat questionable grammaticality is the case of "if whether".  So there are many examples such as "Yet we need to ask if whether being true to yourself is necessarily the highest value." That first *if* there cannot be replaced by *whether*. My guess is that there are probably several ...

Comment: @JohnLawler  ... instances in which interrogative *if* cannot be replaced by *whether* - but I'm still hunting.

Comment: @Dale Stuff the random drive-by downvoter!

Comment: @Araucaria Undeleted.

Comment: What I mean is that "interrogative _if_" **means** a usage of _if_ that can be replaced by _whether_. So you're not going to find any that can't alternate. I.e, "interrogative _if_" is just the result of replacing _whether_ and every usage of _if_ where it can't isn't "interrogative _if_". It's circular unless there is an independent test for "interrogative _if_".

Answer (score 1):

- There are a few verbs where I think "<verb> <interrogative clause>" in general is colloquial-but-acceptable, but where I think *"<verb> whether […]" in particular is ungrammatical; for example, consider ["went to look if […]"](https://www.google.com/search?q="went+to+look+if") vs. *["went to look whether […]"](https://www.google.com/search?q="went+to+look+whether"), or ["I can't think if I've […]"](https://www.google.com/search?q="I+can't+think+if+I've") vs. *["I can't think whether I've […]"](https://www.google.com/search?q="I+can't+think+whether+I've").

  - In part this might be because *whether* is a bit more formal than *if*, so it doesn't work in these colloquialisms because the registers don't match; but I don't think that's a complete explanation, because I don't think the registers are *so* mismatched as to account for why the result sounds so ungrammatical (at least to me). (I'd welcome your thoughts on this.)
- This is probably cheating, but I don't think *if* can be replaced with *whether* in an echo question:

  > "I'm wondering if she, uh . . ." He trailed off.
  >   *"Whether she what?"

  (Note that this isn't completely trivial, since echo questions do allow *some* kinds of substitutions; for example, if the first speaker had said "Hannah" instead of "she", it would still be fine for the second speaker to substitute "she". And I think that echo questions can usually replace the zero complementizer with *that* and vice versa. But even so, I describe this as "probably cheating" because it's probably more a fact about echo questions than a fact about *if* and *whether*.)
- You yourself pointed out in a comment above that something like "ask [if [whether …] …]" is clearly intelligible and grammatical, whereas something like "ask [whether [whether …] …]" is, um, not.
- This is obviously cheating, but hey: colloquial/dialectal *if'n* can never be replaced with *whether'n*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This time I have read your post more carefully. I am guessing that the answer is "no". *Whether* can be used wherever interrogative *if* can. Conditional *if* has restricted distribution (lower type-wise frequency), but is more frequent token-wise. You see this a lot when looking at two words with similar meaning.

I have plotted below the top 50 hits for `verb+if` (red) (discarding instances of conditional *if*) and `verb+whether` (blue) from COCA to give you an idea.

[image: if-and-whether]

Answer (score 0):

In short no.  There are some cases where the word 'if' is not used as a conditional statement.  The word 'if' might be used in an idiom or some other way that doesn't represent a conditional statement.  In those cases whether cannot be replaced in its stead.  Below is an example of how if is used in each case and shows when it can be replaced with the word 'whether'.

If comes from Old English.  Below are the definitions and usages of if.  I will interlace the solution within the solution within the definition below.

> in case that; granting or supposing that; on condition that':
>   Sing if you want to. Stay indoors if it rains. I'll go if you do.

For the above case yes you can replace whether with if

> (2) even though: an enthusiastic if small audience.

in this case no.  Placing whether in place of if does not constitute the meaning of 'even though'.

> (3) whether: He asked if I knew Spanish.

Of course, in this case, it is replaceable.  We can say He asked whether I knew Spanish.

> (4) used to introduce an exclamatory phrase: If only Dad could see me now!

In the case of an exclamatory phrase whether does not fit or make sense.  'If only' is often used an exclamatory or an expression of emotion.

> (5) when or whenever: If it was raining, we had to play inside.
>   noun

In the case above 'when' or 'whenever' can be replaced with 'if'.  Grammatically a rhetorical statement is stated followed by a comma and then a proposed action.  E.g. If I was a millionaire, I'd quit my job.  So, in this case, no you can't replace it.

> (6) a supposition; uncertain possibility:
>   The future is full of ifs.

In this case, the word 'ifs' represents possibilities or uncertainties.  So the answer to this one would be no you can't in this case.

> (7) a condition, requirement, or stipulation: There are too many ifs in his agreement.

The word 'ifs' also can represent conditions to be fulfilled.  So the answer to this one would be no you can't in this case.

> (8) ifs, ands, or buts, reservations, restrictions, or excuses:I want that job finished today, and no ifs, ands, or buts.

In this case 'ifs' is used in an idiom stating in short 'no question about it'.  It might even be considered an exclamatory statement basically said with authority.  The supplemented statement might look like this if updated for someone who doesn't understand the idiom.

> I want that job finished today, and there will be no excuses and you will finish it regardless.
>   or 
>   I want that job finished today!
>   Implying you will not make any excuses be

So the answer to this one would be no you can't in this case.  Whenever 'if' or 'ifs' is used in an idiom you can't replace it with 'whether'.

Comment: Thanks Dale, but I use that example in my question (still a good example though). What I really want to know is examples where we *can* use "if" but we *can't* use "whether". Can you think of any example like that?

Comment: I'll update my solution.